# Creating an issue using a project key and field names with JIRA

Tags: jira

I'm looking at the JIRA api docs. Does anyone know where I can find these credentials?

```
-u charlie:charlie \
```

For the request

```
curl \
   -D- \
   -u charlie:charlie \
   -X POST \
   --data {see below} \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Account Settings-> Security -> Create and Manage api tokens.